# How to vlookup array data with another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, vlookup

I'm new to C, and want to vlookup an array with another array.
This is the array:

```
float A[] = {4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5};
float B[] = {32.567, 46.481, 63.679, 84.438, 109.034, 137.745, 170.851};
```

Now i want to call array B[] by using the array A[] (vlookup in excel). How can i do that in C? Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: The expected results is when i pick A[0] the results is going to be B[0], so for example when i pick 4.0, the results will be 32.567, if i pick 4.5, the results will be 46.481, etc.

Edit 2: This is the code that i used:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        B[i] = A[i];
    }
    printf("%.3f", B);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's almost trivial. Find the index of the the number (e.g. 5.5) in `A` which is 3. Then use that index on `B` (`B[3]` which is 84.438). Must be 5-6 lines of C code.

Comment: Can you give an example what you provide and what you expect as result? `VLOOKUP` in excel just takes one value and searches for that in a given table column and returns the associated value of another column of the same row, so I think the destination array must at least be 2-dimensional

Comment: @Odysseus he has 2 different arrays which can be seen as two columns of a 2D array.

Comment: @Rheza001 you afrer aware that your code just copies the first 5 elements of `A` info the first five elements of `B`.

Comment: The shown code seems unrelated to the described desired behaviour, it overwrites the values in `B` with copies from `A`. That is far from the prose description and gives the unpleasant impression that you show random code to fool the SO users who insist on seeing code. As such, the question lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while actually trying this yourself.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I see no lookup functionality in the given example, its just the same index used in 2 different arrays. Excels `VLOOKUP` for `A[0]` would look for `4.0` within `B` to return its associated value

Comment: guys like i said, i'm new to C.

Comment: I think codereview would suit the best for this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [is this What you want???](https://onlinegdb.com/SJ2drN0NL)

Comment: @houssam yes. this is what i want. Thank you for helping.